# Adaptive payments paypal -no pdt data for pay api operation

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using adaptive payments paypal pay  api     operation to complete a transaction and  i have set both ipn and return url.am successfully getting ipn messages from paypal but not getting pdt data from paypal to my return url and am not sure about why am not getting the data from paypal and i have turned on pdt and auto return in my paypal profile settings

```
 $PayRequestFields = array(
                                'ActionType' => 'PAY',                              // Required.  Whether the request pays the receiver or whether the request is set up to create a payment request, but not fulfill the payment until the ExecutePayment is called.  Values are:  PAY, CREATE, PAY_PRIMARY
                                'CancelURL' => site_url('paypal/adaptive_payments/pay_cancel'),                                     // Required.  The URL to which the sender's browser is redirected if the sender cancels the approval for the payment after logging in to paypal.com.  1024 char max.
                                'CurrencyCode' => 'USD',                                // Required.  3 character currency code.
                                'FeesPayer' => '',                                  // The payer of the fees.  Values are:  SENDER, PRIMARYRECEIVER, EACHRECEIVER, SECONDARYONLY
                                'IPNNotificationURL' => 'http://mysite.com/dev/wallet/ipn_update',                      // The URL to which you want all IPN messages for this payment to be sent.  1024 char max.
                                'Memo' => '',                                       // A note associated with the payment (text, not HTML).  1000 char max
                                'Pin' => '',                                        // The sener's personal id number, which was specified when the sender signed up for the preapproval
                                'PreapprovalKey' => '',                             // The key associated with a preapproval for this payment.  The preapproval is required if this is a preapproved payment.  
                                'ReturnURL' => 'http://mysite.prystino.com/dev/wallet/pdt_update',                                  // Required.  The URL to which the sener's browser is redirected after approvaing a payment on paypal.com.  1024 char max.
                                'ReverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError' => '',          // Whether to reverse paralel payments if an error occurs with a payment.  Values are:  TRUE, FALSE
                                'SenderEmail' => '',                                // Sender's email address.  127 char max.
                                'TrackingID' => ''                                  // Unique ID that you specify to track the payment.  127 char max.
                                );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Payment Data Transfer (PDT) does not work with Adaptive Payments. PDT is something that only works with Payments Standard.